# Add speed to a for loop in void function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to add/control a `for loop` with speed? I do not want to use a coroutine since I have already tried that before. I have added the `for loop` to a normal void function. Long ago, I had seen that the loop was controlled with speed by using `Time.deltaTime` function but I do not remember how it was done. Something like `i = i + 0.1 * Time.deltaTime` but it is not the correct way to do this.

```
void Start()
{
  ...
  ...
   for(float i = 0;i<=1f;i += 0.1f) //Adding speed here?
            {
                CanvasGroup.alpha = i;
            }
}
```

Edit: What I want to achieve is, that the value of i should move from 0 to 1 linearly at a constant speed. It should change its value from 0, 0.1, 0.2,....1 with a delay of 0.2f.

Comment: you could increase `i` by a higher value which you calculate on every iteration.

Comment: In my opinition throttling a `for` loop on a time variable is never "the correct whay to do" whatever it is your end goal is (of which you're not telling us anything about - so we can't propose a different solution either). Mainly because the calling thread would  be blocked for the duration of the loop.

Comment: yeah, you can make your 0.1f a parameter of the function, if you want, but right now your actual goal is rather vague. `i = i + 0.1 * Time.deltaTime` does actually account for the fact that some frames could be "skipped", but it misses the relation between the variable `i` and the time in your scene. nevertheless, we need to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please read about the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I have edited my post now.

Comment: In regular C# I would use a `System.Timers.Timer`. What the normal way of doing this in Unity is I have no idea - but doing it on the main thread (that's calling start) is probably a bad idea. Probably you should be doing it in a co-routine - so perhaps you should revisit why you don't want to do that?

Comment: You mentioned you do not want to use a coroutine. Is there a reason for that? After seeing the update and your goal of incrementing i with a delay, it seems coroutines may be a good choice for you.

Comment: @SpencerStream I did not want to use coroutine because I have to add this particular function for different variables in each void function which will be time consuming. But I guess there is no other way to achieve this so I should create coroutine.

Comment: The Start method CAN be a coroutine, just change void by IEnumerator

Comment: @Jichael `Start()` was just an example. I have 5-8 void functions that I should tackle.

Comment: What are these 5-8 functions doing? Is the sole purpose of each to increase a value at a linear speed?

Comment: You wouldn't use a for loop with Time.deltaTime in this way. Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys thank you for your inputs. I ended up using a coroutine at the end since I could not find a way to achieve a linear speed inside a normal function. All I was looking for a way (if achievable) to control speed inside a normal function. However, there is an alternative to using Coroutine; the way is

```
IEnumerator Way()
{
  ...
  ...
   for(float i = 0;i<=1f;i += 0.1f) 
    {
       CanvasGroup.alpha = i;
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
    }
}

//Alternative given below

void Update()
{
  for(float i = 0;i<=1f;i += Time.deltaTime * speed) 
    {
       CanvasGroup.alpha = i;
    }
}
```

It never hit me that `Time.deltaTime` can be only used inside a recursive function; that is during `Update()`